# Ignoring authentication in unit tests in Clojure web app using Friend?

Tags: authentication, testing, clojure, midje

I'm using friend for protecting some pages in my web application, which is working fine so far. I'm running into issues with my test code, though: I seem to be unable to work around the authentication mechanism or to mock out friend's authorize calls. Things I've tried so far:

- wrapping the request with a map containing the authentication information
- using midje/provided to mock away calls to friend/authorize

The first approach doesn't seem to work because I don't know for certain what I would need to add to the request and the second one doesn't seem to work because midje seems not to see the call to friend/authorize at all. The relevant fact looks like this:

```
(fact "The users page can be fetched successfully"
      (let [req (request :get "/user")
            response (app req)]
        (:body response) => #"(some results)"
        (provided 
          (friend/authorized? anything anything) => true)))
```

And this is the corresponding (running) compojure route:

```
(GET "/user" [] (friend/authorize #{::admin} users))
```

I basically macroexpand-ed the `friend/authorize` call in the midje fact, but still I get two FAILS on the fact due to the authorization. The tests ran successfully before adding the authorization, so it's really the friend authorization part I need to solve.

Are there any best practices do solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on your friend's auth workflow if `authorized?` will get called at all.

Also, I've never could get `midje` to do runtime mocking, so I usually mock functions using [with-redefs](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/with-redefs)

Something along these lines should work for you:

```
(fact "The users page can be fetched successfully"
      (let [req (request :get "/user")
            response (app req)]
        (with-redefs [friend/authorize (fn [roles f] f)]
          (:body response)) => #"(some results)"))
```

Comment: Turns out I was too optimistic about Midje's `provided` functionality. It's closely tied to _one_ checkable, assuming that the mocked code is called in the course of the checkable. I.e. the following works now for me:

      `(fact "The users page can be fetched successfully"
            (app (request :get "/user")) => (contains {:status 200})
            (provided 
               (friend/authorized? anything anything) => true))`

Comment: Right, please add an answer to your own question with your findings!

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I was too optimistic about Midje's `provided` functionality. It's closely tied to one checkable, assuming that the mocked code is called in the course of the checkable. I.e. the following works now for me:

```
(fact "The users page can be fetched successfully" 
  (app (request :get "/user")) => (contains {:status 200}) 
  (provided 
     (friend/authorized? anything anything) => true))
```