# Faking friend credential function using Midje

Tags: clojure, ring, midje

I'm trying to test my routing in isolation using Midje. For some routes that hit the database I have no trouble using `(provided ...)` to isolate the route from a real db call. I've introduced Friend for authentication and I've been unable to fake the call to the credential function.

My credential function looks like this (It's implemented like this because I don't want it getting called just yet):

```
(defn cred-fn
  [creds]
  (println (str "hey look I got called with " creds))
  (throw (Exception.)))
```

The middleware for the routes then look like this:

```
(def app 
  (-> app-routes
      (wrap-json-body {:keywords? true :bigdecimals? true})
      wrap-json-response
      (wrap-defaults defaults)
      (friend/authenticate
       {:unauthorized-handler json-auth/login-failed
        :workflows [(json-auth/json-login
                     :login-uri "/login"
                     :login-failure-handler json-auth/login-failed
                     :credential-fn auth/cred-fn)]})
      (ring-session/wrap-session)))
```

I've also tried without using the auth-json-workflow, the implementation for the routes looks almost identical and I can add that if it helps but I get the same result.

And then my tests look like this (using ring-mock):

```
(defn post [url body]
  (-> (mock/request :post url body)
      (mock/content-type "application/json")
      app))

(fact "login with incorrect username and password returns unauthenticated"
  (:status (post "/login" invalid-auth-account-json)) => 401
  (provided
    (auth/cred-fn anything) => nil))
(fact "login with correct username and password returns success"
  (:status (post "/login" auth-account-json)) => 200
  (provided
    (auth/cred-fn anything) => {:identity "root"}))
```

I then get the following output running the tests:

```
hey look I got called with {:password "admin_password", :username "not-a-user"}
FAIL at (handler.clj:66)
These calls were not made the right number of times:
    (auth/cred-fn anything) [expected at least once, actually never called]
FAIL "routes - authenticated routes - login with incorrect username and password returns unauthenticated" at (handler.clj:64)
    Expected: 401
      Actual: java.lang.Exception
          clojure_api_seed.authentication$cred_fn.invoke(authentication.clj:23)

hey look I got called with {:password "admin_password", :username "root"}
FAIL at (handler.clj:70)
These calls were not made the right number of times:
    (auth/cred-fn anything) [expected at least once, actually never called]

FAIL "routes - authenticated routes - login with correct username and password returns success" at (handler.clj:68)
    Expected: 200
      Actual: java.lang.Exception
          clojure_api_seed.authentication$cred_fn.invoke(authentication.clj:23)
```

So from what I can see the provided statement is not taking effect, and I'm not sure why. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you're running into an issue with when midje applies the replacement, cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21042577/ignoring-authentication-in-unit-tests-in-clojure-web-app-using-friend/21076024#21076024 I don't know when / where exactly your cred-fn will be called.

Comment: The provided is working and I've found a work around that I've posted below

Comment: Midje doesn't mock macros, maybe this could be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently ran into a similar issue, and after some digging I
think I understand why this is happening. Let's take a look at how
the bindings for `auth/cred-fn` change over time.

```
(clojure.pprint/pprint (macroexpand '(defn cred-fn
                                                [creds]
                                                (println (str "hey look I got called with " creds))
                                                (throw (Exception.)))))
(def
 cred-fn
 (clojure.core/fn
  ([creds]
   (println (str "hey look I got called with " creds))
   (throw (Exception.)))))
```

As you can see above, the `defn` macro interns the symbol `cred-fn` in the current namespace and binds it to a Var referencing
your dummy function.

```
(def app 
    (-> app-routes
        (wrap-json-body {:keywords? true :bigdecimals? true})
        wrap-json-response
        (wrap-defaults defaults)
        (friend/authenticate
        {:unauthorized-handler json-auth/login-failed
        :workflows [(json-auth/json-login
                    :login-uri "/login"
                    :login-failure-handler json-auth/login-failed
                    :credential-fn auth/cred-fn)]})
        (ring-session/wrap-session)))
```

Here's the important piece. At compile time, we thread
`app-routes` through a series of functions. One of these functions
is `friend/authenticate`, which takes a map with key `:workflows`.
The value of `:workflows` is a vector populated with the results of
a call to `json-auth/json-login`, which receives `auth/credential-fn`
as a parameter. Remember, we are inside a def, so this is all
happening at compile time. We look up the symbol `cred-fn` in the
auth namespace, and pass in the Var which the symbol is bound
to. At this point, that's still the dummy implementation.
Presumably, `json-auth/json-login` captures this implementation
and sets up a request handler which invokes it.

```
(fact "login with incorrect username and password returns unauthenticated"
    (:status (post "/login" invalid-auth-account-json)) => 401
    (provided
    (auth/cred-fn anything) => nil))
```

Now we're at runtime. In our precondition, Midje rebinds the
symbol `auth/cred-fn` to a Var that references the mock. But the
value of `auth/cred-fn` has already been captured, when we `def`'d
`app` at compile time.

So how come the workaround you posted works? (This was actually the clue that led me to
Eureka moment - thanks for that.)

```
(defn another-fn []
  (println (str "hey look I got called"))
  (throw (Exception.)))

(defn cred-fn [creds]
  (another-fn))
```

And in your tests...

```
(fact "login with incorrect username and password returns unauthenticated"
  (:status (post "/login" invalid-auth-account-json)) => 401
  (provided
    (auth/another-fn) => nil))

(fact "login with correct username and password returns success"
  (:status (post "/login" auth-account-json)) => 200
  (provided
    (auth/another-fn) => {:identity "root"}))
```

This works because, at compile time, the value of `auth/cred-fn` that
gets captured is a function that simply delegates to
`auth/another-fn`. Note that `auth/another-fn` has not been
evaluated yet. Now in our tests, Midje rebinds `auth/another-fn`
to reference the mock. Then it executes the post, and somewhere
in the middle-ware, `auth/cred-fn` gets invoked. Inside
`auth/cred-fn`, we look up the Var bound to `auth/another-fn` (which
is our mock), and invoke it. And now of course, the behavior is
exactly as you expected the first time.

The moral of this story is, be [careful with the def in Clojure](http://squirrel.pl/blog/2012/09/13/careful-with-def-in-clojure/)

Comment: Here's an illustrative example: https://gist.github.com/astahlman/b62b95ab62e48e338246

Comment: Thank you for this! My workaround was good enough to keep me going, but I'm glad I know why it was happening!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure why this is happening but I have a work around. If I replace my `credential-fn` with:

```
(defn another-fn
  []
  (println (str "hey look I got called"))
  (throw (Exception.)))

(defn cred-fn
  [creds]
  (another-fn))
```

And then create a fake for the new function in the test, like this:

```
(fact "login with incorrect username and password returns unauthenticated"
  (:status (post "/login" invalid-auth-account-json)) => 401
  (provided
    (auth/another-fn) => nil))

(fact "login with correct username and password returns success"
  (:status (post "/login" auth-account-json)) => 200
  (provided
    (auth/another-fn) => {:identity "root"}))
```

I get the result I was expecting. `cred-fn` still gets called but `another-fn` doesn't get called due to the `provided`.

If anyone knows why this is the case I'd be interested in knowing. It might be due to the way that the credential function gets called? - https://github.com/marianoguerra/friend-json-workflow/blob/master/src/marianoguerra/friend_json_workflow.clj#L46